# post file times out after 1 min in Kubernetes

Tags: python, reactjs, azure, kubernetes

I have a spa application running on Kubernetes, where it is also deployed an api for different services.

The spa is written in javascript using React.js with nginx as a web server.

The api is written in Python using Flask, with gunicorn as WSGI HTTP Server.

In front of these services there is an nginx ingress controller ([stable/nginx-ingress](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress)).

I can make calls from the spa to the api and everything works fine until I post a file to the api. In this case the request times out after 1 min (independently of the file size).

PS: I guess this has to do with the ingress controller since when spa and api are running on my machine, I can successfully post a file to the api.

How can I solve this?

**Update**

This seems to be related to the Python library [azure.storage.blob](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/12.3.2/).

The logs of the api give the following error

```
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe925032880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve
```